# screen-recorder do not find pom.xml on artifacory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, screen-recording

I want use screen-recorder via Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.monte</groupId>
    <artifactId>screen-recorder</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

I have more one repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>jenkins-releases</id>
    <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-releases</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

When I have my Maven setting.xml is it OK for me, but for other people is it KO.

```
21:30:45 Downloading: http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.pom
21:30:46 
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.pom
21:30:46 
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.pom
21:30:51 
Downloading: https://maven.oracle.com/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.pom
21:30:54 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:30:54 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
16:30:54 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
21:30:54 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.comp:foo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.fii:fuu:jar:1.1.0 -> org.monte:screen-recorder:jar:0.7.7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.monte:screen-recorder:jar:0.7.7: Could not transfer artifact org.monte:screen-recorder:pom:0.7.7 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Authorization Required. -> [Help 1]


http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.pom do not return a real 404:

    {
      "errors" : [ {
        "status" : 404,
        "message" : "File not found."
      } ]
    }
```

My build crashes because it tries to go to the Oracle repository but I would like this to load the jar file which is on http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/monte/screen-recorder/0.7.7/screen-recorder-0.7.7.jar

how can I configure this?

Comment: The simple issue is that this repository is broken for that artifact cause there is pom in there....so it needed to be repaired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build crashes, because it's trying to download pom (metadata file) for the artifact:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.monte:screen-recorder:pom:0.7.7
```

which is **not** located in the repository (only the .jar file resides there).

I would recommend manually downloading the artifact from https://github.com/stephenc/monte-screen-recorder

and installing it in your local repository.

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
    <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```